# Want to find integers from given string in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
SELECT 
(REGEXP_MATCHES('$50M to $100M', '\\$(\\d+)M to \\$(\\d+)M'))[1]::integer AS lower_bound,
(REGEXP_MATCHES('$50M to $100M', '\\$(\\d+)M to \\$(\\d+)M'))[2]::integer AS upper_bound;
```

I am getting nothing in output

| lower_bound | upper_bound |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

i want output as

| lower_bound | upper_bound |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | 100 |

Answer (score 1):

Wuth the two backslashes, you escape the backslash. If you remove one, the query works as expected

```
SELECT 
(REGEXP_MATCHES('$50M to $100M', '\$(\d+)M to \$(\d+)M'))[1]::integer AS lower_bound,
(REGEXP_MATCHES('$50M to $100M', '\$(\d+)M to \$(\d+)M'))[2]::integer AS upper_bound;
```

https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=70704d86-b21b-405c-90c8-b7706e6eb1ef